# Inverse Fourier transform of an $L^2$ function as limit on balls

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

$B_m :=\{x \in \Bbb R^n : ||x|| \le m\}$ and $\mathscr{F}f$
denotes the $L^2$ fourier transform of an $f \in L^2(\Bbb R^n)$.

I am trying to show that

> If $f \in L^2(\Bbb R^n)$ then $f(y)=\lim\limits_{m \to \infty} \int_{B_m} \mathscr{F}f(x)e^{2\pi ix.y} dx$ a.e.

$f \in L^2(\Bbb R^n) \implies \mathscr{F}f \in L^2(\Bbb R^n)$

Now define, $g_m(x)=\mathscr{F}f(x) \chi_{B_m}(x)$

Then $g_m \in L^1(\Bbb R^n) \cap L^2(\Bbb R^n)$ and $g_m \to \mathscr{F}f$ pointwise a.e.

Since, $g_m \in L^1(\Bbb R^n)$  take their Fourier inverse because for them I have the expression for Fourier inversion which should be handy.

> So If I could show that the inverse Fourier transforms of $g_m$ converge to our $f$ pointwise a.e., we are through! How to prove this?

I also tried by Schwarz density kind of arguments but I am getting double sequences and too hard to handle!

Comment: As far as I know, this is an open problem. An internet search will give you a lot of extra information.

Comment: Schwartz, given name Laurent.

Comment: should not this be a.e.? $f(y)$ itself is not even well defined.

Comment: @FedorPetrov When we are talking about $L^p$ functions then pointwise convergence of course implicitly assumes a.e. Any case, I've put it there to avoid trivial confusions.

Comment: @PieroD'Ancona: If I remember this correctly, then the (one-dimensional) Carleson theorem only gives us convergence in the multi-variable case if rectangles instead of balls are used. (This wouldn't be the first time balls are causing trouble here; $\chi_B$ as a Fourier multiplier is unbounded on $L^p$, $p\not= 2$.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been around for an extended period with little prospect of being answered. The comments suggest the problem is open. If someone solves it, they will surely find a better outlet for the result than this forum.

Comment: @Michael Renardy True, but (with small yet non-zero probability) someone may solve the problem just because they learn about it here. Or, if someone solves it and publishes the answer in a proper place, they, or someone else, may write here the reference. Aren't these expected and welcomed evolutions of a post?

Answer (score 1):

Let me reformulate your question: you consider the Fourier multiplier
$
L_m=\mathbf 1_{B_m}(D)
$
defined by the formula
$$
(\mathbf 1_{B_m}(D)f)(x)=\int e^{2iπ x\xi}\mathbf 1_{B_m}(\xi) \hat f(\xi) d\xi.
$$
It is obvious that $\lim_{m\rightarrow+\infty}\mathbf 1_{B_m}(D)f=f$ in $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$. In fact since $f$ in $L^2$ is equivalent to $\hat f$ in $L^2$, you can check
(for $f\in L^2$),
$$
\Vert f-\mathbf 1_{B_m}(D)f\Vert^2_{L^2}=\int_{\vert \xi\vert\ge m}\vert\hat f(\xi) \vert^2 d\xi,
$$
which goes to zero, thanks to the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem. You can also extract a subsequence converging a.e.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't quite prove the statement as your argument can only conclude that we get a subsequence of the balls $B_m$ so that we get pointwise convergence a.e. But my question wants the pointwise convergence to hold true for the original sequence!